# Installing Magento 2.3.5 on Ubuntu 22

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5, magento-install

I'm attempting to install Magento 2.3.5 on Ubuntu 22. However, I'm unable to install Composer version 1, as it's deprecated on Ubuntu 22. Additionally, I've already downloaded the Magento 2.3.5 codebase from https://meetanshi.com/blog/download-magento/.

Also, I am try to install composer 2 through magento 2.3.5 version after show the below screenshot error

Given these constraints, how can I successfully install and run Magento 2.3.5 on Ubuntu 22 ? Alternatively, are there any other reliable sources from where I can download Magento 2.3.5 along with its corresponding database?[image]

Comment: hello dear i also replay your answer. after that you get any error so please replay me.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to resolve this error.

(not recommended)

1. Add **--ignore-platform-reqs** in composer command, As per your above screenshot it's look like terminal PHP version issue.

Command will be :- `composer create-project --repository-url=YOUR-URL --ignore-platform-reqs`

(recommended)

2. Solve php version issue at your command prompt to fix this issue

Both way will resolve the above error but it's upon you which way you use.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the requirements to install magento2. And for the error, check the problem-1 it already says you try to install magento2.3.5 with php8.1.

Try this, in command line

which composer && which php
[image]

You'll get something like this

now try this command and try with php7.4 or php7.3

COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 /usr/bin/php(your_php_version) /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:your_magento_version magento_folder_name -vvv

Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Magento version 2.3.x then a requirement of PHP version 7.1 and 7.2.

https://www.magetop.com/blog/magento-system-requirements/

so you can change PHP version.

step 1: apply the below commands for all PHP versions.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config PHP
```

Step 2: After that, you can disable PHP version 8.1 and enable PHP version 7.1 or 7.2

```
sudo a2dismod php8.1   => disable PHP version 8.1
sudo a2enmod php7.1    => enable PHP version 7.2
```

Step 3: `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1`

Step 4: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Step 5: Check your PHP version.

```
     php-v
```

Step 6: Create your database.

Step 7: `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.5 upgradem235`

here required for public key and private key you can show your Magento marketplace account. so you can get it.

Step 8: `php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/yoururl" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="dbname" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --admin-firstname="admin12" --admin-lastname="user" --admin-email="admin12@example.com" --backend-frontname="admin"`

Step 9: `sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/`

I hope that is work.

Answer (score 0):

> **First, you need to install your required PHP version and then disable the current PHP version. Please check the command below to install PHP version 7.3.**

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y php7.3

sudo apt-get install php7.3-common php7.3-opcache php7.3-cli php7.3-gd php7.3-curl php7.3-mysql php7.3-pdo-mysql php7.3-soap php7.3-intl php7.3-bcmath php7.3-gd php7.3-curl php7.3-mysqli php7.3-socket php7.3-mbstring php7.3-dom php7.3-mbstring php7.3-xml php7.3-mbstring php7.3-xsl php7.3-mbstring php7.3-socket php7.3-mbstring php7.3-soap php7.3-zip php7.3-fpm

sudo a2enmod php7.3                                                   --> to enable php version
sudo a2dismod php8.1                                                  --> To disable php version
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3                    --> to set default php version

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

**Reference Website Links for Installing PHP Version**

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-multiple-php-versions-on-one-server-using-apache-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-18-04
2. https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-multiple-php-version-with-apache-on-ubuntu-20-04/

> **Afterward, you need the old Composer version, which you can update using a single command.**

```
composer self-update 1.10.12 <Add-version>

composer self-update 2.2.18 <Add-version>

composer self-update --rollback

composer --version
```

**Reference Link for Updating Composer Version**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598028

> **Once you have updated your PHP version and Composer version, you can run the following command. Additionally, you can add this parameter if the package has some dependency issues: --ignore-platform-reqs.**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.5 <folderName>
```

**Reference Link for Installing Magento**

1. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html?lang=en#example---minor-release